# A problem with making phyloseq object - Found more than one class "phylo" in cache

Tags: r, validation, error-handling, r-package, phyloseq

I`m trying to make a phyloseq object in R this is my script:

```
Phyloseqb<- qza_to_phyloseq(
metadata = "E:/pesticide 4 months work result/pesticide bacteria/pesticidebacteria/metadata1.txt",
features= "E:/pesticide 4 months work result/pesticide bacteria/pesticidebacteria/table_final_rarefied.qza",
tree="E:/pesticide 4 months work result/pesticide bacteria/pesticidebacteria/asvs-tree.qza",
taxonomy="E:/pesticide 4 months work result/pesticide bacteria/pesticidebacteria/classification.qza")
```

But I`m getting an error :

```
Found more than one class "phylo" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'phyloseq'
Also defined by ‘tidytree’ ‘RNeXML’
Found more than one class "phylo" in cache; using the first, from namespace 'phyloseq'
Also defined by ‘tidytree’ ‘RNeXML’
Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “phyloseq” object: 
 Component sample names do not match.
 Try sample_names()
```

How can I solve it ?

I tried to create another Phyloseq object but I`m getting the same error

Comment: It'll be difficult to answer this question since your post isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What packages did you load before running this code?

Comment: Sorry for the missing information, I used the qiime2R package. On the other hand, I figured out the problem there was a mismatch between the sample metadata and the other files ( count_table, taxonomy ) so I rectified sample metadata and it worked well, Thank you ^^